# Google Maps Places API radius parameter not working

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using Google MAPS API in python:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

To get the information about a place I am using

```
result = gmaps.places("restaurant",location=(lat,lng),radius = r)
```

Now on changing the radius r to different values( I have tried for as low as 1) I always get 20 results. This is not possible, because you cannot have 20 restaurants in 1 m. Any fix for this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it is posible cause the API is intended to work like that, as stated in the documentation:

"a location and a radius — You may bias results to a specified circle by passing a location and a radius parameter. This will instruct the Places service to prefer showing results within that circle. Results outside the defined area may still be displayed. "

Taken from:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests

Comment: Is there no way by which we take results only within that circle?

Comment: I just can have some ideas, like find a way to draw the circle and for each predictions location you ask IF the location is inside the circle then you show it, if not the don't show it, I think there are methods for this but can't remember by heart. If i find something ill let you know